# Join, round and count the seniority

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle database. I have to connect a few tables.

*For every employees show last_name (table employees), job_title (from jobs table),start_date and end_date (from table job history) and the months and years beetwen them (count time of working). I should remember about employeers who doesn't have those data. Last thing I should round seniority to full numbers.*

This task is a difficult for me, so I was trying to do as much as I can by myself. I'm the beginner.

My idea:

```
select last_name
  from employees
  join jobs
    on employees.department_id = jobs.department_id;
join start_date, end_date from job_history on job.department_id = job_history_id
   select start_date('03/19/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY') end_date(03 / 09 / 2010, 'MM/DD/YYYY') "seniority"
     from job_history round(seniority, 2)
```

Can I ask about some help here?

Comment: What is Seniority here?

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' definitions, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample.

Comment: seniority is time between start_date and end_date. I need to count the months and years between them @BikashRanjanBhoi

Comment: @Mureinik I will try. By the tables I mean databases with data.

Comment: @Mureinik I will try. By the tables I mean databases with data. I have one huge database called Tables. It included many other databases like Employees, Job History, Job ect. For example employees included first_name, last_name, phone_number ect.  I use SQL Developer and JDK8 environment. I know that I should use one of the JOIN function, but I don't know which one.

Comment: You should at least show us the columns that are relevant here. For instance, your query shows that both the employees table and the jobs table have a column department and you use these to join the tables. That would indicate that every employee in a department does all the jobs that exist for the department. Strange. Isn't it rather that an employee can have only one job? Maybe restricted to the jobs available in their department? So is there a job_id in the employee table maybe? Tell us what columns exist in employees and jobs and department and which are the primary keys.